# The origin of the restricted isometry property (RIP)

Tags: reference-request, compressive-sensing

I have been looking for the origin of the [restricted isometry property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restricted_isometry_property) (RIP). Many papers cite the origin of the RIP in the following paper

- Emmanuel Candès, Terence Tao, [Decoding by Linear Programming](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0502327), February 2005.

but I cannot understand where the definition came from. Some others papers say that the RIP is very similar to the [Johnson-Lindenstrauss lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%E2%80%93Lindenstrauss_lemma) (JL), and in fact it is, but I am not sure that that it is the origin of the RIP. However, I haven't been able to find this origin, mathematically.

On the other hand, how can the RIP be proved with certain matrices? Let's say for example Gaussian matrices or a Fourier matrix?

Comment: To address your 2nd question. Proving that a matrix satisfies the RIP is an NP hard problem. You would have to enumerate the possibilities and test them. For a Gaussian matrix, it can be shown that it satisfies the RIP with a high probability,

Comment: @David can you explain me how it can be shown that a Gaussian Matrix satisfies the RIP with high probability. You can send me the paper if you are able and want to.

Comment: The reference I have is: R. Baraniuk, M. Davenport, R. DeVore, and M. Wakin, “A simpleproof of the restricted isometry property for random matrices,” Constructive Approximation, vol. 28, no. 3, pp. 253–263, 2008.[Link here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/2817/ed70d621b3183f41fedee845722ddd93bb1b.pdf)